# DNA storage using reed solomon

Tags: coding-theory

The problem is as follows:
29040 DNA molecules carry 300 bits each, with up to 20% packet loss.
Choose the field, generator, and discuss to complexity of encoding and decoding.

I view 4 bases in DNA as a whole and this corresponds element in $GF(2^4)$. But I have no idea how to choose the length of code and how to use $29040$ and $300$. Could you give me some hint about how to encode with DNA using Reed Solomon Codes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 4 bases C,G,T,A can be encoded by 2 bits, no?

Comment: First note the one nucleotide corresponds a symbol over $GF(2^2)$, since there are 4 different DNA bases. You probably want a Reed-Solomon code of length $29040$ over the field of size $2^{300}$, such that each molecule has length $300/2=150$ and corresponds to one symbol of the code.